# PHP socket_recv newline issue

Tags: php, sockets, newline, php-5.4

I have the following that reads from a buffer and send a message to the socket.

Depending the client (classic, telnet, windows, linux , putty, etc) it behaves differently.
It send the line after the newline, other times, character by character.

I need to add a control so it only sends the message after a newline is detected.

Any ideas?

```
foreach ($this->changed as $key => $socket) {
    $buffer = null;
    while (socket_recv($socket, $buffer, 1024, 0) >= 1) {
        $this->sendMessage(trim($buffer) . PHP_EOL);
        unset($this->changed[$key]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is the sendMessage function

```
function sendMessage($msg)
{
    foreach($this->clients as $client)
    {
        @socket_write($client,$msg,strlen($msg));
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you post your `sendMessage` function source code? could your buffer contain a carriage return? or a `PHP_EOL` ?

Comment: I just added it. Thanks. The buffer could contain a newline character (It's a telnet connection)

Comment: in your `socket_recv` and `socket_write` you will have to check on errors and do some more error handling, think about adding a log file as well, this way you have more details about what you received and what you are sending, and can also log the errors using functions like `socket_last_error()`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($this->changed as $key => $socket) 
{
    $buffer = null;
    $tempbuffer=null;
    while(socket_recv($socket, $tempbuffer, 1024, 0) >= 1) {
        if(strpos($tempbuffer,'\n')==false)
            $tempbuffer.=$buffer;
    }
    if($buffer==null)
       $buffer=$tempbuffer;

    $this->sendMessage(trim($buffer) . PHP_EOL);
    unset($this->changed[$key]);

    break;

}
```

Comment: That works only for the first socket, if there are 2 connections, the second gets nothing at all. :(

Comment: In fact it hangs the socket only for the first connection, it doesnt process the new ones.

Comment: Perhaps use \r instead of \n, or both